# Maximize All Windows on Every Virtual Desktop Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

```
+F10::
WinGet, MyCount, Count
GroupAdd, AllWindows
Loop, %MyCount%    {
  WinMaximize ahk_group AllWindows
}
```

This works to maximize all windows on the active virtual desktop, however it does not maximize any windows on any other virtual desktops in Windows 10. Looking for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
F1::
DetectHiddenWindows, On
WinGet, id, list,,, Program Manager
Loop, %id%
{
    this_ID := id%A_Index%
    WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (class = "")
            continue
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %this_ID%
        If (title = "")
            continue
        If (title = "SubFolderTipWindow")
            continue
    If !IsWindow(WinExist("ahk_id" . this_ID))
            continue
    WinMaximize, ahk_id %this_ID%
}
return

IsWindow(hWnd){
    WinGet, dwStyle, Style, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if ((dwStyle&0x08000000) || !(dwStyle&0x10000000)) 
        return false
    WinGet, dwExStyle, ExStyle, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (dwExStyle & 0x00000080)
        return false
    WinGetClass, szClass2, ahk_id %hWnd%
    if (szClass2 = "TApplication") {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```